# Django-error OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2 / cairo-gobject-2

Tags: python, django

When I do manage.py makemigrations
An error like this occurs

```
PS C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop-master> python .\manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop-master\manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 350, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 376, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop-master\config\urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    path('order/', include('order.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop-master\order\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .views import *
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop-master\order\views.py", line 36, in <module>
    import weasyprint
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop\venv\lib\site-packages\weasyprint\__init__.py", line 393, in <module>
    from .css import preprocess_stylesheet  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop\venv\lib\site-packages\weasyprint\css\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from . import computed_values
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop\venv\lib\site-packages\weasyprint\css\computed_values.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .. import text
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop\venv\lib\site-packages\weasyprint\text.py", line 14, in <module>
    import cairocffi as cairo
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop\venv\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    cairo = dlopen(ffi, 'cairo', 'cairo-2', 'cairo-gobject-2')
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProject\onlineshop\venv\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 38, in dlopen
    raise OSError("dlopen() failed to load a library: %s" % ' / '.join(names))
OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2 / cairo-gobject-2
```

I can't figure out a workaround.
How can I solve this?
'''
pip install cffi
'''
Requirement already satisfied: cffi in c:\users\user\pycharmproject\onlineshop\venv\lib\site-packages (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\user\pycharmproject\onlineshop\venv\lib\site-packages (from cffi) (2.19)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the cairocffi package has an issue or not and even it is correctly installed or not. And try to install it again, so maybe these issues will be solved.
Also check your database. like when you write python manage.py make migrations , if your database is not created as superuser, so it will give you errors
if your packages are already satisfied then try to uninstall it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: and now run python manage.py runserver
OSError: cannot load library 'gobject-2.0-0': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'gobject-2.0-0'